# How can I get Users day time by using timestamp and utc_offset?

Tags: javascript, date, time, timezone, momentjs

I need to get the day time(time between 9 am - 8 pm) of users and I have a timestamp of their joining date, timezone abbreviation, and utc_offset. I am sending the notification from firebase cloud function in their day time.

following are the info I have:

> timezone_abbreviation = CST
>
> timestamp = 1578422400991
>
> utc_offset = -21600

If I can get the timezone name then I can get the day time using moment_timezon method tz()

```
const time = moment.tz(timestamp, timezone_name).format('HH:mm');
const hour = +temp.split(':')[0];
const isDayTime = hour >= 9 && hour < 20;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide examples of the timezone name, timestamp and offset values? Usually if you have the timezone in an IANA representative location like Europe/Paris then you don't need the offset, you can use moment.tz or the built–in Intl.DateTimeFormat to get the time in that location for a given timestamp.

Comment: @RobG I have updated the question with an example of timezone,  offset and timezone_abbreviation I have.

Comment: This is not a good approach as timezone names and abbreviations are not standardised and many are ambiguous, e.g. CST can be US central standard time, China standard time or Cuba standard time (there is also Australian central standard time that may use CST too). IANA representative locations have been created to solve these issues and deal with historic and daylight saving changes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually with given utc offset it is very easy to get necessary information.

[source](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/03-manipulating/09-utc-offset/)

As for timezone abbreviations you have to loop through all zone names and get the one which has provided abbreviation. **It is unreliable and not recommended.**

[source](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/zone-object/abbr)

I made a quick snippet with two solutions.

Check it out!

```js
const timestamp = moment().valueOf();
const timezone_abbreviation = "IST";
const utc_offset = "+05:30"; // or 330

const getTimezoneFromAbbreviation = (() => {
  const timezones = moment.tz.names().map(zone => moment.tz.zone(zone))

  return (abbreviation) => {
    const filteredTimezones = timezones.filter(zone => zone.abbrs.includes(abbreviation));
    
    if(!filteredTimezones.length) {
      return null;
    }
    
    if(filteredTimezones.length > 1) {
      //console.log(filteredTimezones.map(zone => zone.name));
    }
    
    return filteredTimezones[0];
  }
})()

const timezone = getTimezoneFromAbbreviation(timezone_abbreviation)
const getHourFromTimezone = (timestamp, timezone) => {
  return Number(moment.tz(timestamp, timezone).format('HH'));
}

const getHourFromUTCOffset = (timestamp, utc_offset) => {
  return Number(moment(timestamp).utcOffset(utc_offset).format('HH'));
}

let hour = getHourFromTimezone(timestamp, timezone.name);
let isDayTime = hour >= 9 && hour < 20;

console.log({
  hour,
  isDayTime
})

hour = getHourFromUTCOffset(timestamp, utc_offset);
isDayTime = hour >= 9 && hour < 20;

console.log({
  hour,
  isDayTime
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.28/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.28/moment-timezone-utils.js"></script>
```

Comment: Jozef, It is not returning the correct values. As my utc_offset is 19800 and the daytime is not correct.

Comment: utc_offset 19800 ? I looked in google and this is Asia/Calcutta

Comment: You have to provide utc_offset in minutes or hour with minutes with following pattern "+05:30". In your case you would have to divide 19800/60 to get minutes

Comment: This approach simply doesn't work reliably. E.g. using CST and offset of +08:00 (China standard time) it returns an IANA representative location of America/Atikokan, which is -05:00 and does not have daylight saving.It should return Asia/Shanghai.  Other places that are US CST (-06:00 standard, -05:00 daylight saving) might use America/Monterrey, so their DST is ignored. If it can't find a match for an abbreviation, it throws an error.